# return function input in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

```
function count() {
    var arr = [];
    for (var i=1; i<=3; i++) {
        arr.push(function () {
            return i * i;
        });
    }
    return arr;
}

var results = count();
var f1 = results[0];
var f2 = results[1];
var f3 = results[2];
f1(); // 16
f2(); // 16
f3(); // 16
```

I don't understand why all three inputs are 16? I thought there were 1, 4,9

Comment: var squareCount = (function(){
      var c = 0;
      return function(){
        c += Math.pow(c, 2);  if(c === 0){ c = 1; return c; }
        return c;
      }
    })(); squareCount(); squareCount(); squareCount();

Answer (score 1):

Because each of `f1,f2,f3` are `function(){ return i * i; }` (note theres no argument to that function, the `i` inside there is the last value `i` took (`4` in this case, because of the for loop).

Comment: but i has been set or execute from 1 to 3, otherwise how come the compiler know it is 4 in the case?